# Angular JS + CodeIgniter: Cannot read session data during $http ajax calls

Tags: php, ajax, angularjs, codeigniter

I'm trying to use codeigniter sessions to store state between ajax calls.
In one of the urls i'm setting session using

```
$this->session->set_userdata("user", "harry");
```

But When I'm trying to access the value "user" from another url, I'm getting false

```
$this->session->userdata("user");
```

returns false.

What am I doing wrong here? I know that session is being set in the first URL because I could echo the value immediately after that.

Answer (score 0):

> Sessions will typically run globally with each page load, so the
>   session class must either be initialized in your controller
>   constructors, or it can be auto-loaded by the system

If your not Auto-loading the session library, initialize it in a Custom Controller that your other Controllers will inherit, such as MY_Controller. You would need to load the Session library in each Controllers __construct() otherwise.

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
   public $currentUser = NULL;

   public function __construct()
   {
       if(is_null($this->currentUser))
           $this->_checkUserHasLoggedIn();
   }

   protected function _checkUserHasLoggedIn()
   {
       // $this->session->set_userdata(array('uid'=>'0'))
       // This would only be set if a user is logged In
       // via a Authentication library

       if($this->session->userdata('uid') && $this->session->userdata('uid') !== 0)
       {
            $this->currentUser = new StdClass();
            $this->currentUser->ID = $this->session->userdata('uid');
            $this->currentUser->Group = $this->session->userdata('group');
            $this->currentUser->Name= $this->session->userdata('name');
       }

       return;

   }
}
```